# Estimating household expenditure per capita of two population groups based on income survey

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares

I am working on a project that requires information about household expenditure per capita of two different groups: (i) the first one's members have an income per capita equal or above a certain (deflated) value; and (ii) the second one's members have an income per capita below that same threshold. The country does not carry out a periodic household expenses survey, but it does carry out a periodic household income survey, and provides data about aggregate household consumption (GDP).

I can easily delflate income and expenditure data, I can rely on household income survey data to calculate the percentage share of each group each year, and I have a sample of just over 20 years. So, in order to estimate the aggregate consumption of each group I thought of doing a  regression (OLS) of aggregate consumption of families based on these percentages.

Something like Y = β(1)P(1) + β(2)P(2) + ε, where P(1) represents the percentage of the sample whose income is equal to or greater than the threshold and P(2) the remaining percentage , so that P(1) + P(2) = 1.

I know this is far from an ideal solution but I can't figure any other way to find a proxy to the real values.

I'll appreciate any comment/suggestion about this matter.